# How to get bytes out of a PNG file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, png, byte

How do I get bytes out of a PNG file using C#, (Reason for this:I need to pass the PNG as a string in an XML file.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)

[System.Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx)

```
System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you have the PNG file in memory:

- create a System.Drawing.Bitmap object out of it
- Serialize it to a memory stream using Bitmap.Save() (pass in PNG as the encoding)
- Use MemoryStream.GetBuffer() to retrieve the underlying byte array for the MS
- Use Convert.ToBase64String(byte[], 0, memoryStream.Position) to convert it to a base64 string